# Error:not_found, Status Code:404, Reason:Database does not exist

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Hyperledger Fabric v1.2

Hyperledger Composer v0.20

When installing a business network archive on a Fabric network I get the following error:

> Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
>   Command failed

When I go 'docker logs peer0.org1.example.com' I see an error where it can't find the database on CouchDB docker container.

Anyone know why this is happening, or solutions to this problem?

Comment: its likely (check with docker ps -a and 'exited' containers) that the container died. More importantly, the peer container doesn't know how to communicate with the couchdb container if up.  Similar issue reported here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588680/hyperledger-fabric-peer-container-cannot-communicate-with-couchdb-container - see the suggestions in the answer. Is the couchDB container on the same docker network? Have you got 4Gb or greater available?. Is this in a Cloud environment? Did you check the couchDB logs?

Answer (score -1):

I've found the problem that was causing this issue.

The problem was the connection profile in the createPeerAdminCard.sh file. The peer wasn't set as an endorsing peer. The peer needed to be set as an endorsing peer so that it can create a database in couchDB in the case that the database it's trying to get doesn't exist.

Comment: The connection profile doesn't control the peer setup, it merely describes an existing setup so has no influence over how the peer works. Also unless explicitly set to false in the connection profile, any user of the connection profile will be told it is an endorsing peer.